# Regular expressions for 301 redirect

Tags: regex, redirect, regular-language

How can I redirect `http://example.com/news.php?id=268&page=25` and all pages like  `http://example.com/news.php?id=X&page=Y` to another page using regular expressions?

I tried using `http://example.com/news.php?id=/d&page=/d`.

Comment: It looks like a simple pattern where you just use `(\d+)` for the numbers. What's the problem?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I’ve tried using the /d pattern in http://example.com/news.php?id=/d&page=/d but I was not sure about the correct syntax

Comment: It's backslash, not forward slash. Any regular expression tutorial should show the correct syntax.

Comment: And you need `+` to match more than one digit. And put a capture group around it so you can copy the number to the replacement URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digits are matched with `\d`, not `/d`. To match at least 1 digit, you need to add the `+` quantifier. And to capture the numbers so you can copy them to the replacement URL, you need a capture group around it.

You also need to escape certain characters that have special meaning in regular expressions: `.` and `?`.

```
http://example\.com/news\.php\?id=(\d+)&page=(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'http://example.com/news.php?id=268&page=25';
$pattern = '/^[^\?]+\?id=(\d+)&page=(\d+)$/';
$replacement = 'https://mynewdomain/with/too/many/subpaths/page.php?id=$1&page=$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```